# Cakephp - find thread

Tags: cakephp, model, find, cakephp-1.3

i have a tweet table that stores tweets and its replies like this

tweet(id, parent_id, tweet_message, time)

where parent_id is a self id if its a tweet and is of parent id if its a reply. how to do a find to pull out tweets where id = parent_id

example:

tweet(1, 1, 'My name is Harsha', 'time')  parent_id = id since its a tweet and not a reply
tweet(2, 1, 'Hello Harsha', 'time') parent_id = 1 which tells its a reply to the tweet with id = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should theoretically work. Look at the SQL Debug log to find out what it does if there are any errors

```
$conditions = array(
    'Tweet.id = Tweet.parent_id'
    );
$tweets = $Tweet->find('all', $conditions);
```

Or if you are looking for a specific ID you can do

```
$conditions = array(
    'Tweet.id' => 1,
    'Tweet.parent_id' => 1
    );
$tweets = $Tweet->find('all', $conditions);
```

you can use MySQL `<>` not operator to search for all nonroot tweets

```
$conditions = array(
    'Tweet.id' => 1,
    'Tweet.parent_id <>' => 1
    );
$tweets = $Tweet->find('all', $conditions);
```

or

```
'Tweet.id <> = Tweet.parent_id'
```

Comment: thanks. the first one was what i was trying. i was doing it like this $conditions = array(
    'Tweet.id' = 'Tweet.parent_id'
    );

Comment: now for the replies how can i do it the other way round where     'Tweet.id is not equal to Tweet.parent_id'

Comment: You should however consider using tree behaviour as suggested by Nik. Cake's Model behaviours are quite useful if your model grows complex.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use the [Tree behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/view/228/Basic-Usage)?

Probably this suggested from Yarek T will work but only for one level.